# PHP issue - Unable to place static URL in code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am frankly not into coding but need help in modifying an existing code.
As you can see in below code, the script tries to call the URL -> store or destination whichever it maybe.
I simply want to prefix a static URl before the below URL is generated.
For example - if through below code I get : www.amazon.com, I'm simply trying to find a way where instead of direct link showing up -> it should be something like:

www.domain.com/script.php?id=www.amazon.com 
I think we need to modify the code somewhere here. Hence basically -> "www.domain.com/script.php?id=" should be prefixed in ALL outgoing URLs.

Any help is really appreciated!
(hope i dont get banned >_<)

```
/**
     * Get destination url
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @param bool $store_url_if_empty
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function get_destination_url( $store_url_if_empty = true ) {

        $url = '';
        if ( ! $this->_wpc_destination_url && $store_url_if_empty ) {
            $url = $this->get_store_site_url();
        } else {
            $url =  $this->_wpc_destination_url;
        }

        if ( ! $url ) {
            $url = $this->store->get_url();
        }

        return $url;
    }
```

Comment: Just before return statement.  Prepend static url to $url

Answer (score 1):

Just before return statement

```
$static = "www.domain.com/script.php?id=";
$url =$static.$url;
return $url;
```

Comment: Thanks Uchit. There is 1 more thing I'd require. I've updated my original query. Kindly assist in the 2nd query - where I want the post ID to be passed on to the static URL.
PS: Ive tried this: return 'http://localhost/website/redirect/?coupon='. $coupon_id.'&id=' .urlencode($url); but it didnt work.

Comment: If it is so .. remove that

Comment: yes that was a typo. Anyway much of the work has been done :)